# Why is id generated for local variable only when flush is made before save?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Lets say I have three classes.

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "child_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name ="parent_id")
    Parent parent;

    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<GrandChild> grandChildren = new HashSet<>();
}

public class GrandChild {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "grandchildid", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    Child child;
}
```

If I then create a new `GrandChild grandChild` via `parent.getChilds().get(0).getGranChilds().add(grandChild)` and save the entity via `parentRepo.save(parent)`. The local variable `grandChild` will not have a `id`. But if I first flush and then save, the local variable will have a id? Is this something you normally would do?

I tought this would happend when you save and then flush. But seems only to be working when i FIRST flush then save.

Adding the grandChild:

```
   GrandChild grandChild = GrandChild.builder().name(name).build();
   Parent parent = parentRepo.findAll().get(0);

   Optional<Child> optional = parent.getChilds().stream().findAny();

   optional.ifPresent(child -> child.getGrandChildren().add(grandChild));
```

(This is just code for the example, so dont mind the ugliness).

Saving with flush after (no id generated for the local variable, entity is still saved):

```
parentRepo.saveAndFlush(parent);
System.out.println(grindChild.getId()); // null
```

Flush before (local variable gets the id):

```
parentRepo.flush();
parentRepo.save(parent);
System.out.println(grandChild.getId()); //not null, value exists
```

The ID is, in both cases, generated in the database.

Comment: May you show the code samples of both cases you are talking about?

I assume you use spring data?

Comment: Correct. I'll update.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that no Id is generated in the database itself? You call .save() method without assigning the result to any variables?

Comment: My bad. Id is always generated in the database. Just the local variable that differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that different cascades action was made based on if a flush was made before or after the save.

If I flush before I save, the entity will be saved via the `ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH` cascade which uses the same object reference as the local variable.

If I flush after I save, the entity will be saved via the `ACTION_MERGE` cascade which does a copy on the entity before the ID is generated, thus a different reference which means the local variable will not have a ID.

In both cases `saveWithGeneratedId(...)` was called in `org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener` class. Just with different object references.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you might save the instance without flushing and assigning the result to a local variable. Please see the following javadoc comment from `CrudRepository` interface:

```
/**
 * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
 * entity instance completely.
 *
 * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the saved entity will never be {@literal null}.
 */
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

I think you could try the following approach:

```
Parent persistentParent = parentRepo.saveAndFlush(parent);
```

Where `persistentParent` should have the generated Id value available.

**UPD**

The Id is generated at the moment of synchronization with the database. So it gets available only after flushing the session.

Comment: But why is the ID assigned if I just flush before I save?

Comment: But the id is not generated if I save and THEN flush. I must flush BEFORE I  save.

Comment: @gel most likely this behaviour is caused by spring.jpa.open-in-view=true default spring-boot (do you use spring boot?) option. When you flush - the transaction manager saves your instance automatically.

Comment: I fully understand that. What I don't understand is why `saveAndFlush` generates the id in the database but the local variable still has null as id. But if I `flush()` then `save()`, the Id is there. (The parent is already persisted by the way, it's the grandchild which is the newly created entity).

Comment: This kind of behavior may be also caused by the fact that the actual commit happens after returning the value. So you could try to refactor your logic to a more fine-grained stat: to have `save()` of `saveAndFlush()` within the method return statements and just invoke these multiple methods on demand. The drawback of this approach is higher load to db server. Are you sure you need their ids in the code? What for?

Comment: I understand where you getting at. Not to be that guy, but my question was not if I really need to use the Id or not.